# SQL -- Remove duplicate pairs

Tags: sql, sqlite, graph, unique, distinct

I'm using an SQLite to store a set of **undirected** edges of a graph using two columns, u and v. For example:

u       v

1       2

3       2

2       1

3       4

I have already been through it with SELECT DISTINCT * FROM edges and removed all duplicate rows.

However, there are still duplicates if we remember these are undirected edges. In the above example, the edge (1,2) appears twice, once as (1,2) and once as (2,1) which are both equivalent.

I wish to remove all such duplicates leaving only one of them, either (1,2) or (2,1) -- it doesn't really matter which.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

If the same pair (reversed) exists take the one where u>v.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u,v
FROM table t1 
WHERE t1.u > t1.v
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM table t2 
            WHERE t2.u = t1.v AND t2.v = t1.u 
    )
```

Comment: I used a variation of this query to help me find polygons that shared an edge. My issue, before this query, was that I had double the number of results, with parcel_id_1 in the first column, parcel_id_2 in the second column, but also the reverse in the next row. `SELECT DISTINCT v1.pin14
FROM parcels v1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT v2.pin14 FROM parcels v2
            WHERE st_touches(v1.geom, v2.geom)
    )`

Answer (score 4):

This will find all the duplicates:

```
SELECT t1.u, t1.v FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2
 ON t1.u = t2.v AND t1.v = t2.u
```

This will delete the duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM table t1 WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table t2 WHERE t2.u = t1.v AND t2.v = t1.u AND t1.u > t2.u)
```

Note that this will not delete duplicates like (2, 2) but I think you got those already with SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: You might want to clarify *which* u and v you are selecting.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to leave only the uniques. So for the above example I'd be left with: (1,2) , (3,2) , (3,4).


FYI, I believe an equal solution to yours would be: SELECT u AS u1, v AS v1 FROM edges WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM edges WHERE u=v1 AND v=u1)

Comment: Thanks... I have no problem selecting the duplicates, and by extension, deleting (all) the duplicates, just not sure how to delete all the duplicates except for one, if you get what I mean.

Comment: Try the DELETE statement that I added (please note, it was about for a couple of minutes with a bug in the last operator, which should be >, not <>).

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but can you clarify what you mean by "table t1"? Is this shorthand for "table AS t1" where table is the name of the table? Because I don't think that SQLite support this syntax -- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

Comment: Yes, it's short for (your table name goes here) AS t1 and yes, SQLite allows you to leave out the option AS (at least according to the documentation: http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#single-source)

Comment: Indeed, you are right Jonathan.  I need to look at this a little further, but I think you'll be able to remove the t1 alias on the first line, change the remaining "t1"s to "table" and keep the t2 alias.  I'll have to try it, however.

Comment: I've set up a little test DB that I'm using. I'm also trying a few things, will let you know if I figure it out :) Please let me know if you do first -- I'm sure you will, my SQL knowledge is rather poor...

Comment: OK, done the first bit: SELECT u AS u1, v AS v1 FROM edges WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM edges WHERE u=v1 AND v=u1 AND u > v). This will return the duplicates to be removed. Now all I need to is pass this to a DELETE and it should work, just not sure how to do that! (This is a slight modification on the original alternative I posted above, adding the constraint that u>v, hence only returning a single row, adding in the > constraint from yours).

Comment: Had a poke around online and it seems this may not be possible in SQLite, may need to run the SELECT to get the rows into a temporary table, then use DELETE... not the neatest solution, but only need to do this once, so guess it will do!

Answer (score -1):

Testing for 9 numbers so I'm adding 9 numbers to two tables:

```
 declare @num  int
 set @num =1
 while @num<10
 begin 
 insert into t2 values (@num)
 insert into t1 values (@num)
 set @num +=  1 
 end
```

Then coupling uniques without any repetition:

```
 select t1.u, t2.v
 from t1 cross join t2
 where t1.u>t2.v
```