# Removing reciprocal itemsets in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query which generates a list of order numbers and the item sets in two colums [Item1], [Item2]. The problem is that it also generates the inverse of the pairs so I always end up with 2 rows for each item pair and I only want one. This is essentially the same as **undirected** edges.

eg. {1234, ProductA, ProductB}  and {1234, ProductB, ProductA} are duplicates and one should be removed.

I tried this but it didn't work (0 results). I had found the code in this question [SQL -- Remove duplicate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651936/sql-remove-duplicate-pairs)

```
SELECT
    OrderId,
    Item1,
    Item2
FROM
    cte_pairs t1
WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 
        OrderId,Item1,Item2 
        FROM cte_pairs t2
        WHERE t2.OrderId=t1.OrderId 
            AND t2.Item1=t1.Item2
            AND t2.Item2=t1.Item1
    )
```

**Edit - Inner CTE Table**
Added the code here for CTE incase there is a way to prevent the duplication higher in the chain per the comments.

As a note, vOrderItems is at a sku level. Since Group1Name is a category, the SELECT DISTINCT is there to remove those duplicate rows.

```
SELECT
    a.OrderId,
    a.Group1Name Item1,
    b.Group1Name Item2
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            OrderId,
            Group1Name
        FROM
            vOrderItems
    ) a

    JOIN

    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            OrderId,
            Group1Name
        FROM
            vOrderItems
    ) b
    ON
        a.OrderId=b.OrderId

WHERE
    a.Group1Name<>b.Group1Name
```

)

Comment: Seems to me that if your CTE is generating duplicate (reciprocal) pairs in the first place, it's either a bad CTE, or a bad table structure.  I would fix this problem higher up the chain.

Comment: I added in that CTE as part of my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in your CTE:

```
a.Group1Name<>b.Group1Name
```

To this:

```
a.Group1Name<b.Group1Name
```

And the CTE will not produce reciprocal rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could "sort" the items and then use standard `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    OrderId,
    CASE WHEN Item1 < Item2 THEN Item1 ELSE Item2 END AS Item1,
    CASE WHEN Item1 < Item2 THEN Item2 ELSE Item1 END AS Item2
FROM
    cte_pairs
```

This would guarantee that identical rows generate the exact same order of items and duplicates will be discarded