# Postgresql remove duplicate reversed pairs

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgrouting

I have this table:

```
 origin     destination

new york      seattle
new york      chicago
new york      portland
seattle       new york
seattle       chicago
chicago       new york
```

I have to build a graph so I need to remove all the duplicated reversed pairs to have:

```
origin      destination oneway

new york      seattle     0
new york      chicago     0
new york      portland    1
seattle       chicago     1
```

I already read this post:
[SQL -- Remove duplicate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651936/sql-remove-duplicate-pairs)
but it's not useful for me because I have string filed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select origin, destination,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from t t2
                          where t2.origin = t.destination and t2.destination = t.origin
                         )
             then 0 else 1
        end) as one_way
from t
where origin < destination
union all
select origin, destination, 1
from t
where origin > destination;
```

An alternative method uses window functions:

```
select origin, destination, (cnt = 1)::int as one_way
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by least(origin, destination), greatest(origin, destination)) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where origin < destination or
      (origin > destination and cnt = 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

One option with `row_number` and `count` using `least` and `greatest`.

```
select origin,dest,case when cnt_per_pair=1 then 1 else 0 end as one_way
from (select t.*,row_number() over(partition by least(origin,dest),greatest(origin,dest) 
                                   order by dest) as rnum,
      count(*) over(partition by least(origin,dest),greatest(origin,dest)) as cnt_per_pair
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table is a Cartesian product
*(What i see in that snippet, that means you have reversed duplicate of every row in your table)*
and you don't care what will be on each side, it is much easier then everything above

```
select origin, destination
from table t
origin > destination
```

Otherwise you can use other answers