# Left Join with same table and group by is returning duplicated tuples with reverse order

Tags: sql, join, group-by, hsqldb

I'm trying to query a database(not owned by me) that contains the following columns :

```
NumEpoca (epoch), Turma(class), Dia (day - indicates day of the week), 
Hora (hour - each value indicates a 30mins time, a 3h class generate 6 tuples), 
Disciplina (course), TipoAula (type of class, theoretical or practical),     
Sala (classroom)
```

This is basically a class schedule, so for a given Class, in the same day of the week I can have in one week a practical class and in the other a theoretical class.

Now, I want to get for a given day, the minimum and max hour (so I can calculate the starting and ending hour of the class), but I also want to get the classrooms for them, and I don't know at priori, if it's going to be a theoretical or practical class.

Also, certain classes are only practical, and some are only theoretical, so I just want 1 classroom.

The query I'm doing, gives me basically everything but

```
LectureDetails(beginDate=2020-05-26 15:30:00, endDate=2020-05-26 18:30:00, classroom=L_H1/G.0.08)
LectureDetails(beginDate=2020-05-26 15:30:00, endDate=2020-05-26 18:30:00, classroom=G.0.08/L_H1)
```

as you can see here, I get the same class (that starts and ends at the same hour, for the 2 classrooms Teo and Pract. But I only need 1 tuple for that day and I'm getting L_H1/G.0.08 and G.0.08/L_H1.

```
"SELECT a1.Dia,MIN(a1.Hora),MAX(a1.Hora),a1.Sala, a2.Sala FROM Aulas as a1 LEFT JOIN Aulas as a2 " +
                    "on a1.Sala <> a2.Sala and a1.Disciplina = a2.Disciplina and a1.NumEpoca = a2.NumEpoca and a1.Turma = a2.Turma " +
                    "and a1.Dia= a2.Dia and a1.Hora = a2.Hora " +
                    "where NumEpoca = ? AND Turma = ? AND Disciplina=?  GROUP BY a1.Dia,a1.Sala,a2.Sala"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Getting only one copy of a given pair of values in a row is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please format code reasonably. PS Just googling 'duplicated tuples with reverse order' from your title returns SO hits answering this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL -- Remove duplicate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651936/sql-remove-duplicate-pairs)

Comment: I don't want to remove duplicated tuples, since they aren't even duplicated. They just have their order switched. And I need to get things without the orders, not just delete something.
Shawnt00 gave me the answer that I needed.

Comment: You don't seem to have read the linked Q&A, because they are clearly talking about what you are & the answer says exactly what the first line of the accepted answer does &--clearly--the asker just happens to be using the word "duplicate" to describe having (a,b) & (b,a) & using the word "remove" to mean not select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have eliminated the mis-ordered results by using `a1.Sala < a2.Sala` instead of the inequality.

But that's not really the approach you want anyway. Try something like this:

```
SELECT Dia, MIN(Hora), MAX(Hora),
    MIN(Sala),
    CASE WHEN MIN(Sala) = MAX(Sala) THEN NULL ELSE MAX(Sala) END
FROM Aulas
WHERE NumEpoca = ? AND Turma = ? AND Disciplina = ?
GROUP BY Dia
```

Comment: Wow, I was looking at aggregation functions so I would have to group them and I was like "no way I'm using this", 20 minutes later they save me. Thanks a lot for the help!